# What does /u mean in PCRE?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've looked just about EVERYWHERE to try to find this, Google searched, looked all through the PHP Manual, and nothing has given me the answer to it.

So I am trying to use the following example `preg_replace` and I'm not sure as to what '/u`' is :

```
$string = preg_replace(array("/\\$replace/u"), array('something'), $string);
```

But I'm not sure as to what searching for `u` actually does for my output.

I know that `i` means that the string isn't going to be searched case sensitively, and was thinking that `u` does the opposite?

Comment: A hint: php.net contains all the necessary information on regex modifiers.

Comment: These suffixes are called pattern modifiers, they are listed here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php